# Регулярные выражения. Поиск слов по набору букв

Tags: регулярные-выражения, поиск

Помогите составить регулярное выражение для поиска слов только по определённому набору букв. Т.е. Есть слово "зажигалка" в результате в искомых словах могут использоваться только буквы из этого слова и в том же количестве.

Нужно найти все слова, состоящие из этих букв. Т.е. "глаз", "газ", "галка" и т.д. В общем, как в игре "Слова из слова"

Answer (score 2):

Если речь о перестановке букв, то:

```
^(?=.*з)(?=.*а.*а.*а)(?=.*ж)(?=.*и)(?=.*г)(?=.*л)(?=.*к)[зажиглк]{9}$
```

Если речь просто о подмножестве, то так:

```
^(?!.*з.*з)(?!.*а.*а.*а.*а)(?!.*ж.*ж)(?!.*и.*и)(?!.*г.*г)(?!.*л.*л)(?!.*к.*к)[зажиглк]+$
```

Comment: Не совсем то. Как я понял эта строка ищет слова именно из 9 букв, а нужно найти все слова состоящие из этих букв. Т.е. "глаз", "газ", "галка" и т.д. В общем как в игре "Слова из слова"

Comment: @StasP., ответ дополнен.

Comment: @Qwertiy, а в каком из диалектов *re* оно должно сработать так, как требуется в условии?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, в любом? Я проверял на js. А в каком оно не работает (при условии наличия отрицательного предпросмотра)?

Comment: @Qwertiy, из известных (и доступных) мне срабатывает только в *pcre*. да, вы наполовину опровергли моё утверждение. но лишь наполовину: дополнительный код для преобразования исходного набора символов всё ещё требуется (я исхожу из своего понимания требований: исходное слово долно быть произвольным).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, а в каком случае он бы не требовался? о_О

Comment: @Qwertiy, например, посмотрите второй абзац моего ответа. в регулярное выражение можно подставлять непосредственно исходное слово.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, т. е. под немодификацией подразумевается возможность вставить слово как есть в единственное место некоторой регулярки? Если речь о динамическом формировании регулярки, то всё равно ещё экранирование нужно. Да и вставлять куда-то. И что-то не уверен, что от этой возможности можно получить какие-то преимущества.

Comment: @Qwertiy, о каком «преимуществе» может быть речь? условие задачи (чуть перестроенное, но, надеюсь, с полным сохранением смысла): «есть произвольный набора букв. как с помощью регулярного выражения проверить, является ли другой произвольный набор букв подмножеством первого?» // без **существенного** программного преобразования первого набора, увы, ничего не выйдет (к несущественному преобразованию , я думаю, вполне можно отнести добавку каких-нибудь символов в начало/конец/середину набора).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, я не понимаю, какая разница, является ли преобразование существенным или несущественным. На что это вообще влияет? А ещё, где грань между ними?

Comment: @Qwertiy, грань, на мой взгляд, вполне очевидна: либо можно подставить исходный набор *как есть*, либо его надо **программно** (т.е., в соответствии с некоторым алгоритмом) преобразовать. всё.

Answer (score 2):

условие «в том количестве» (точнее, как понятно из комментария к другому ответу, «в количестве, не большем заданного») с помощью известных мне [стандартов регулярных выражений](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Standards) выполнить невозможно. если, конечно пользоваться только движком регулярных выражений, без дополнительного кода (см. ниже).

если условие про количество опустить и если слова идут по одному в строке, то, например, так:

```
$ echo -e 'глаз\nгаз\nмозг\nгалка' | grep '^[зажигалка]\+$'
глаз
газ
галка
```

---

под дополнительным кодом я имею ввиду:

1. преобразование искомой строки в отсортированный список букв с квантификатором количества для букв, встречающихся более одного раза. например: `зажигалка` преобразовать в `^а{1,3}?г?ж?з?и?к?л?$` (или чуть по-другому, только с квантификаторами количества и без квантификатора `?`: `^а{0,3}г{0,1}ж{0,1}з{0,1}и{0,1}к{0,1}л{0,1}$`)
2. преобразование слова на входе в отсортированный список букв. например: `мозг` → `гзмо`, `глаз` → `агзл`, `заза` → `аазз`.

если такие преобразования выполнить, то движок, понимающий bre (basic regular expressions), вполне справится:

```
$ echo -e 'гзмо\nагзл\nаазз' | grep '^а\{1,3\}\?г\?ж\?з\?и\?к\?л\?$'
агзл
```

---

пример выполнения описанных преобразований средствами posix-утилит:

1. преобразование исходного слова в регулярное выражение bre:

   ```
   $ echo 'зажигалка' | sed 's/./&\n/g;s/.$//' | sort | uniq -c | \
    sed -r 's/\s*([0-9]+)\s*(.*)/\2\\{0,\1\\}/;1s/^/^/;$s/$/$/' | \
    sed ':a;N;s/\n//;ta'
   ^а\{0,3\}г\{0,1\}ж\{0,1\}з\{0,1\}и\{0,1\}к\{0,1\}л\{0,1\}$
   ```
2. сортировка букв:

   ```
   $ echo 'глаз' | sed 's/./&\n/g;s/.$//' | sort | sed ':a;N;s/\n//;ta'
   агзл
   ```

---

**обновление**: в своём [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/521892/178576) *Qwertiy* продемонстрировал, что без второго из описанных мною преобразований можно обойтись, если использовать стандарт *pcre* ([*perl compatible regular expressions*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions)), в котором есть функция предпросмотра (*look-ahead*).

первое преобразование в таком случае может быть сделано средствами posix-утилит, например, так:

```
$ w='зажигалка'; echo $w | sed 's/./&\n/g;s/.$//' | sort | uniq -c | \
 sed -r 's/^\s*([0-9]+)\s*(.)$/echo \\(?!\\(.*\2\\)\\{$((\1+1))\\}\\)/e;1s/^/^/;$s/$/['$w']+$/' | \
 sed ':a;N;s/\n//;ta'
^(?!(.*а){4})(?!(.*г){2})(?!(.*ж){2})(?!(.*з){2})(?!(.*и){2})(?!(.*к){2})(?!(.*л){2})[зажигалка]+$
```

полученное регулярное выражение работает корректно:

```
$ echo -e 'мозг\nглаз\nзаза' | grep -P '^(?!(.*а){4})(?!(.*г){2})(?!(.*ж){2})(?!(.*з){2})(?!(.*и){2})(?!(.*к){2})(?!(.*л){2})[зажигалка]+$'
глаз
```

Comment: Не-а, не учитывает количество букв. `заза` тоже сматчит, а `з` только одна в исходнике

Comment: такому требованию невозможно удовлетворить с помощью известных мне движков регулярных выражений: обязательно потребуется дополнительный программный код.

Comment: alexandr barakin, в вопросе разве было условие о Unix?

Comment: @СашаЧерных, а unix тут при чём? я показал пример регулярного выражения для стандарта [bre (basic regular expression)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Standards).

Comment: _"с помощью известных мне стандартов регулярных выражений выполнить невозможно"_ - не согласен :)

Comment: @Qwertiy, предложите своё **новое** решение (то, которое вы уже привели, явно не подходит под требуемые условия).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, ответ дополнен.

Answer (score 0):

\b([з|а|ж|и|г|а|л|к|а]){9}\b цифра обозначает сколько букв должно быть в слове

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [справке](/help/how-to-ask).